# How to order values inside group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

Consider the following SQL Server table:

```
  ID  |   X   |   Y
------+-------+-------
   1  |   1   |   1
   2  |   1   |   2
   3  |   1   |   3
   4  |   2   |   40
   5  |   2   |   500
   6  |   3   |   1
   7  |   3   |   100
   8  |   3   |   10
```

I need to select the ID of the row that has the maximum value of Y grouped by x, i.e:

```
  ID  |   X   |   Y
------+-------+-------
   3  |   1   |   3
   5  |   2   |  500
   7  |   3   |  100
```

The query will be nested several times so an optimal performance solution is required...

Comment: You wrote "MS SQL" but tagged it with "mysql", I'll give my answer for MySQL (maybe valid for MS SQL, too).

Comment: No problem, I will try to translate to MS SQL...

Comment: Then my link gives you three solutions. Look, we even have a tag for that here on Stack Overflow. ;)

Comment: @AndreKR: If I'm not mistaken, `greatest-n-per-group` is meant to stand for 'greatest N *items* per group'.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/greatest-n-per-group/info the tag is for both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup:

```
 declare @MyTable table(ID int, X int, Y int)

 insert @MyTable
 values
    (   1  ,   1   ,   1),
    (   2  ,   1   ,   2),
    (   3  ,   1   ,   3),
    (   4  ,   2   ,   40),
    (   5  ,   2   ,   500),
    (   6  ,   3   ,   1),
    (   7  ,   3   ,   100),
    (   8  ,   3   ,   10)
```

Query:

```
;with cte
as
(
    select *, row_number() over(partition by X order by Y desc) RowNumber
    from @MyTable
)
select Id, X, Y
from cte
where RowNumber = 1
```

Result:

```
Id          X           Y
----------- ----------- -----------
3           1           3
5           2           500
7           3           100
```

The query is for MS SQL 2005+.
The setup will work in MS SQL 2008+.

Comment: @Denis Yaremov - I am confused. Do you have MySQL or MS SQL? The post starts with `Consider the following MS SQL Server table`. The reason why I ask is because if you have MS SQL then cte query will be more efficient solution for you. You can see this, if you compare execution plans.

Comment: @Denis Yaremov - you asked for the best performance solution, but selected the answer that is not the best performance solution :).

Comment: Hi Alex, I should say that the solution I've selected doesn't work as I expected at all, I've didn't selected your solution because I've didn't understood how it was working...

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, many times this type of question...  Added keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN" to pre-optimize the query by enforcing the "PreQuery" first.

```
select STRAIGHT_JOIN
      YT.*
   from 
      ( select x, max(y) HighPerX
           from YourTable 
           group by x ) PreQuery
      join
         YourTable YT
            on PreQuery.X = YT.X 
            AND PreQuery.HighPerX = YT.y
```

Comment: In MS SQL this will be less efficient then cte.

Comment: @Alex Aza, ok, This is generic that would work across almost all databases -- as the poster mentioned, they are running MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic:

[The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Comment: Using uncorrelated queries seems like logical solution, but I've thought that it is bad practice making joins by fields other than identity (fields)..

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bad practice (that's why they're called *relational* databases), but it's generally not performant unless you're working with small data sets.

Comment: At least in MySQL joining by primary key isn't slower or faster than joining by any other indexed column. Using subqueries, however, can be slower because of MySQL's poor optimizer, that's why it also gives two solutions without subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

Also see what you can do with row_number() function
http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2007/08/27/multipurpose-row-number-function.aspx

Comment: This is definitely  useful link